# element heights locked to browser height

Tags: html, css, browser, height, containers

this must be a previously-answered question, but i'm unable to find an answer that covers it.

the html/css below does a couple of things i find strange, and it does them in FF4/5, Chrome 12, and Safari 5, so at least this strangeness is consistent across browsers.

the strangeness in question:

- the body element, with height:100%,
  stops at the bottom of the browser
  window.  scrolling down reveals the
  white <html> beneath the grey
  <body>.
- the blue <contentBorder> also stops at the bottom of the browser window.

both these, despite being contained, all the way up the DOM, in elements with height:100%. apologies if this question has already been answered, and thanks for directing me to a descriptive explanation of what's happening here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>simple height test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        html {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #999999;
        }
        #contentBorder {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #666699;
            float: left;
        }
        #contentContainer {
            width: 200px;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: #333333;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contentBorder"></div>
    <div id="contentContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the height for `body` and `html` as 100% will set them to be 100% of the browser window's height. If you want the background to fill the total vertical height of the page, then it should work if you remove `height: 100%` from the first CSS block.

Comment: thanks.  this answers my question, though i'm finding that i didn't really frame my question properly.  essentially, i want an element to respond to the height of a sibling element, but with a slightly better understanding of CSS now, i believe that's not possible.  relative height is relative only to the parent element, and the parent element does not resize based on its child elements.  right?  (i think i'll make this its own question, if i can't find it already asked here...)

Comment: @ericsoco Parent elements normally do indeed stretch to the size of its contents, including any child elements *unless* they are position: fixed/absolute; or floated. If you take a look at the jsfiddle in my answer, I made a version not requiring floats. If you do need to make an element stretch to its floating children, take a look at http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/

Answer (score 1):

Kyle S is on to something - try setting only body to 100% height, not html element.

see http://jsfiddle.net/A49vb/

I took the liberty of putting your #contentContainer inside of #contentBorder so that any (future) content will stretch both divs.